# Give a service in one tenant access to a subscription in other tenant

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have a `serviceA` in `TenantA` which needs to deploy resources to a `subscription_X` that is in `tenantB` say using ARM SDK. This means serviceA must be having rights to create the resource group in the subscription_X too.

How can `serviceA` in the `tenantA` get a contributor access to the `tenantB`'s `subscription_X` ?

ServiceA is a micro service running in AKS or VM

Comment: By `serviceA` you mean `Service Principal`?

Comment: just added more details. it can be a service principal/managedidentity

Answer (score 0):

A Managed Identity can only be used within the tenant that is linked to the subscription it is in.
So it won't work for this scenario.

A service principal can be used, but it would need to be made into a multi-tenant app + an admin from tenant B would have to go through a manually written admin consent URL for it to show up in their tenant.

I'd say the easiest approach is for tenant B admin to define an app registration/service principal in tenant B.
If you use certificate authentication, you'd generate the certificate and give them the public key so that they can assign it to the app in their tenant.
If using client secret, they will have to add it and send it to you.

Comment: There can be multiple subscriptions in tenant B, so I think the right way would be your option2 - which is service principal + multi tenant app.

It would be great if you could provide some details/docs on how to do that.

Comment: Multiple subscriptions in one tenant doesn't really affect assignments, it's the same for the third option to assign the needed roles. It's a different story if you have more tenants of course. I'll have to check if there is some official docs on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know it is not possible.

Considering Managed Identities are scoped to a single subscription, I don't think it is possible for you to manage resources in a different subscription using a Managed Identity in another subscription.

Similarly Service Principals are special kind of Azure users that gets created automatically when you assign access to resources in an Azure AD (tenant). They also can't be shared across tenants.

What you have to do is register your Azure AD application in the target tenant. As a result of that, a new Service Principal will be created in that tenant. You can then assign proper Azure RBAC role to this Service Principal so that it can perform necessary operations on Azure Subscriptions where it has been assigned a role. You can either use Client ID/Client Secret or Client ID/Client Certificate of your Azure AD application to authenticate the Service Principal.